# What is the maximum number of HttpSession attributes

Tags: session, servlets

How many attributes we can save in HttpSession using,

```
session.setAttribute("someName", "abc");
```

Is there any limit?  Can we save 'n' number of attributes in a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no limitation, and that depends on your computer memory.

In [Documentation of this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is nothing about limitation.

Comment: Ok.  Thanksss!  Yes, there is nothing mentioned in docs about the limits. And to test dependency on computer memory, I will set some number of attributes in session simply using for loop.  If I got satisfactory answer then I will post it here.  Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

I have 4 GB RAM.  I am running application on Tomcat 7.
Also set -Xms512M -Xmx1524M arguments.
I am able to set & get 1,00,00,000 attributes in HttpSession.

```
//WORKING CODE
for(Long i=1L; i<=10000000L; i++) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("TXN_"+i, i);
}
for(Long i=1L; i<=10000000L; i++) {
    logger.info(request.getSession().getAttribute("TXN_"+i).toString());
}

//Below code causes OutOfMemory Error (Heap Space)
for(Long i=1L; i<=100000000L; i++) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("TXN_"+i, i);
}
for(Long i=1L; i<=100000000L; i++) {
    logger.info(request.getSession().getAttribute("TXN_"+i).toString());
}
```

Saving 1,00,00,000 attributes in HttpSession is more than enough for my application.